# how to make Numbers preceded by japanese characters(Long Text) to come in a single line in browser in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I ma using a combination of some japanese characters along with numbers without giving space in between numbers, say like "新しいフォルダ000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", then numbers are coming to the second line. 
but if use "新しいフォルダaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", then all are coming in only one line.

But, if I use word-wrap:break-all, then iam able to bring only characters to second line, forcefully.
By default the numbers are always coming in new line.
Please help me how make numbers along with japanese characters to come in one line.

Comment: Can't you just set the width of the element large enough so that the text never wraps?

Answer (score 0):

That's true, You cannot break word with CSS. you definitely need to use Javascript function like,

```
var str = "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
str = str.replace(/(.*?)/g, "<wbr />");
document.getElementById("...").innerHTML = str;
```